# extract two types of text from a string

Tags: java

I have a string that contains two (N in the general case) types of data, delimited by open and close marks:

```
type1a <: type2a :> type1b <: type2b :> type1-c
```

There are numerous real-life examples of such intermixed data, e.g. code and comments (and probably javadoc comments), plain html and the scripting part, etc.

I want to split the string into strings that contain different types of data; just an array/list of `("type1a", "type2a", "type1b", "type2b", "type1-c")` is not enough because I need the types of data.

Coding this would (and probably will) be a funny exercise, but there must be an existing library that already offers this functionality.

Is there a Java library offering such functionality, namely, splitting a string into multiple fragments of different nature, preserving information on each fragment's type?

Comment: With 11k rep, you should probably know that asking for library recommendations is off-topic on StackOverflow. It's also quite unclear what you are looking for if you were asking this as a coding question - what sort of output *do* you expect (your example of what's not good enough doesn't tell what *is* good enough)

Comment: Hello, if I understand your question correctly, you could consider this as a custom grammar. If so you could use language processsing libraries such as ANTLR or design patter Interpreter to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> read(String str) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(str)) {
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s*<:\\s*|\\s*:>\\s*");

        while (scan.hasNext())
            res.add(scan.next());
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: is it any different from `Arrays.asList(myString.split("<:|:>"))` ? Well, the problem is that I am not sure if each `<:` is followed by `:>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you want to extract a list of pairs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String opening = "<:";
    String closing = ":>";
    String str = " type1a  <:  type2a :> type1b <:  type2b :> type1c   <: type2c :>  ";

    String[] splitted = str.split(closing);
    List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String item : splitted) {
        if (item.trim().isEmpty())
            break;

        int index = item.indexOf(opening);
        String first = item.substring(0, index).trim();
        String second = item.substring(index + opening.length()).trim();
        Pair<String, String> p = new Pair<>(first, second);
        list.add(p);
    }

    for (Pair<String, String> p : list) {
        System.out.println(p.getKey() + " " + p.getValue());
    }
}
```

will print

```
type1a type2a
type1b type2b
type1c type2c
```